# Recursion output not as expected

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods, substring

Is anyone able to figure out how this recursion code works and why it outputs what it does? 
Maybe you could include the steps it goes through to get to what it outputs? Thank you so much! The code is attached... ( it outputs bdefh).
Please also note that I am a beginner.

```
public class difficult {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mysteryMix("abcdefgh!");
    }

    public static void mysteryMix(String str) {
        System.out.println("i entered loop");
        System.out.println(str);
        int length=str.length();
        if(length>=3)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println("I entered if statement");
            mysteryMix(str.substring(0,length/3));
            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println("FOR REAL PRINT: " +str.substring(length/3,2*length/3));
            System.out.println("length "+length);
            System.out.println(length/3);
            System.out.println(2*length/3);
            mysteryMix(str.substring(2*length/3));
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying to attach it

Comment: Welcome to SO. A. A similar [question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541424/how-does-recutsion-work-the-method-call-precedes-and-follows-a-print-why-is-bde) was already marked as duplicate. B. To make you code and post easier to follow please format the code, use capitalization in your test. C.  " it outputs bdefh" can not be right for the code posted. D. Follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Relevant statement                                      Output
=================================================       ======================
mysteryMix("abcdefgh!")
  System.out.println("i entered loop");                 i entered loop
  System.out.println(str);                              abcdefgh!
  System.out.println(str);                              abcdefgh!
  System.out.println("I entered if statement");         I entered if statement
  mysteryMix("abc")
    System.out.println("i entered loop");               i entered loop
    System.out.println(str);                            abc
    System.out.println(str);                            abc
    System.out.println("I entered if statement");       I entered if statement
    mysteryMix("a")
      System.out.println("i entered loop");             i entered loop
      System.out.println(str);                          a
    System.out.println(str);                            abc
    System.out.println(...);                            FOR REAL PRINT: b
    System.out.println("length "+length);               length 3
    System.out.println(length/3);                       1
    System.out.println(2*length/3);                     2
    mysteryMix("c")
      System.out.println("i entered loop");             i entered loop
      System.out.println(str);                          c
  System.out.println(str);                              abcdefgh!
  System.out.println(...);                              FOR REAL PRINT: def
  System.out.println("length "+length);                 length 9
  System.out.println(length/3);                         3
  System.out.println(2*length/3);                       6
  mysteryMix("gh!")
    . . . and so forth
```